# $\sqrt[3]{2}$ isn't a root of $x^2 + px + q \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: number-theory

How can we show that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ isn't the root of $x^2 +px +q$. It looks obvious that minimal polynomial with root $\sqrt[3]{2}$ should have degree $3$. But how it can be shown formally? I thought about Vieta's theorem and represent second root in terms of $q$ and $p$. Then represent it in terms of $p^2 - 4q$. Any hints?

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube

Also, this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number

Comment: **Beware** that the argument in the accepted answer has an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a  root of $x^2 +px +q\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Since, by definition, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root also of $x^3-2$, then $x^3-2$ and $x^2 +px +q$ have a common root. Take the division, then the remainder $R(x)=(p^2-q)x+pq-2\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$  and 
$$R(\sqrt[3]{2})=(p^2-q)\sqrt[3]{2}+pq-2=0$$
which contradicts the fact that $\sqrt[3]{2}\not\in \mathbb{Q}$.

P.S. The conclusion holds also when  $p^2=q$. In that case $pq=2$ which means that $p^3=2$, that is $p=\sqrt[3]{2}\in \mathbb{Q}$, contradiction.

Comment: **Error:** that argument divides by zero if $\,p^2 = q\ $ when deducing $\, \sqrt[3]{2} = (2-pq
)/(p^2-q)\in\Bbb Q\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque if $p^2 = q$, then $x^2 + px + p^2 = (x+p/2)^2 + 3p^2 /4 = 0$ gives us that $x_{1,2} \in \mathbb{C}$. That's just something to add.

Comment: @openspace Of course there are (various) ways to fix the argument. But without any mention that this case needs to be handled there is no way to tell whether the intended argument is incomplete or incorrect. This is a common error in problems like this so it is important to make students aware of such pitfalls.

Comment: @BillDubuque Are you sure that there is an error in my answer? I did not divide by $p^2-q$ (which can be zero), you did!

Comment: @RobertZ  Yes, it was most certainly erroneous as written: either it was incomplete (major gap in said case) or it divided by zero.

Comment: An easier fix: if the remainder is the zero polynomial then $\,x^3-2 = (x-r)(x^2+px+q)$ so it has a rational root $\,r,\,$ contradiction (e.g. via Rational Root Test).  We don't need to know the actual values of any coefficients (so we don't need to *explicitly* perform the division).

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[3]2$ is a root of $X^3-2$ which is irreducible (Eisenstein), thus it is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3][2]$.